# laravel jetstream photo profile preview doesn't appear

Tags: laravel-9

When in try to update the photo profile, by clicking in the button 'Select A New Photo'
the image preview doesn't appear
i've tried

clear chrome browser cache
the link for storage folder -> php artisan storage:link
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:clear

jetstream fileSystem ->

```
jetstream.php ->   Features::profilePhotos(),
```

Answer (score 0):

change app url in env file
from APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).